# How to improve this LINQ query for search

Tags: c#, linq

Can I improve this LINQ query

```
var filter = from Dep in deptlist
where (Dep.DepNm.StartsWith(txt1.Text.ToLower()) 
  || Dep.DepNm.StartsWith(txt1.Text.ToUpper())
  ||Dep.DepNm.Contains(txt1.Text)) 
select Dep;
```

Comment: Which LINQ provider is that? It matters. LINQ-to-Objects? LINQ-to-SQL? etc?

Comment: Thanks. It is LINQToObjects and i am making observablecollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you do a `.Text`, `.Text.ToUpper()` and `.Text.ToLower()` **of the fixed value** per item; (the `ToUpper()` etc being relatively expensive); you can lift this out:

```
string text = txt1.Text, upper = text.ToUpper(), lower = text.ToLower();
var filter = from Dep in deptlist
             where Dep.DepNm.StartsWith(lower) || Dep.DepNm.StartsWith(upper)
                   || Dep.DepNm.Contains(text)) 
             select Dep;
```

I'm *assuming* here that `.DepNm` is trivially cheap. If this is actually an expensive property to query, you can use `let` to minimise the calls:

```
var filter = from Dep in deptlist
             let name = Dep.DepNm
             where name.StartsWith(lower) || name.StartsWith(upper)
                   || name.Contains(text)) 
             select Dep;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filter = from Dep in deptlist
where Dep.where(d => d.DepNm.ToUpper().Conatins(txt1.Text.ToUpper())) 
select Dep;
```

If it's possible in your solution, add lambda expressions. So you saved at least one line :)

---

EDIT:
Forget what I was saying, this is MUCH shorter:

```
var filter = deptlist.where(d => d.DepNm.ToUpper().Conatins(txt1.Text.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think your answer does the same as the LINQ in the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

I think it's faster because there is less conditions.

```
var filter = from Dep in deptlist
where (Dep.DepNm.StartsWith(txt1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
||Dep.where(d => d.DepNm.ToUpper().Contains(txt1.Text.ToUpper()))
select Dep;
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is good , i refer viewing this link that relation with search and improvement   [use query linq in search with empty field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225437/use-query-linq-in-search-with-empty-field)

this is multiple choice for filling or not filling `textbox`, but this answer is work when :
you are one field filling or two field filling or .. 7th field filling .