# Filter values in stored procedure on the basis of white spaces

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

Suppose I have 3 records, named 'PROBLEM', 'BIG PROBLEM', and 'VERY BIG PROBLEM' in the column `Name` and I want to filter in the `stored procedure`. My SP can take one parameter, that is `@p` and I want find records on the basis of that parameter. I am stuck in the condition where I should find 'VERY BIG PROBLEM' if I get parameter either

1. VE (As 'VERY' starts with 'VE')
2. BI (As 'BIG' starts with 'BI')
3. PRO (As PROBLEM start with 'PRO')

One solution could be using `Where name like '%' + @p + '%'`, but it can give undesired results like if I search for 'Phil' and give parameter as 'Ph' then result will be 'Phil' and 'Joseph' as both has 'Ph' keyword. Is there any solution? As I am using `ADO.Net`, `C#` solution also be appreciated.

**My Goal**

If I search 'VE' then 'VERY BIG PROBLEM' should come as a result if I use `name like @p + '%'`, but the same result should come on 'VE', 'BI' and 'PRO' also. Its like splitting the value on the white space and matching the result which each word.

I can give C# example:

```
string name = 'VERY BIG PROBLEM';
string[] terms = name.Split(' ');
```

Note the `term` array contains 3 values; that is 'VERY', 'BIG', and 'PROBLEM'.

So if I search for either 'VE', 'BI', or 'PRO' it should give me the same result. If it's still unclear, suppose a scenario where we want to search for the name of a cricketer 'Abraham Benjamin Devilliers'. Let my parameter be 'Abrah', 'Benj' or 'Dev'; it should search 'Abraham Benjamin Devilliers' for me.

Comment: Not sure what you want on this Where @p like '%' + @p +%? Why would you use @p instead of Name since the records are stored in the Name column?

Comment: Ok. Now, what does it mean by Where name like "%PH%", since the column name is only three, VE, BI, and PRO? Please share your objective. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want only to match begining letters then you must try somthing like @p + '%'. this might can help you.

Comment: Update question for being more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search like starting with you can use like `@p+'%'` as suggested by @ankit.

If you want c# solution which is not good as you will fetch more data and then filter out. You can use `linq` to filter data.

You can use `StartsWith` in linq to filter data
Example :-[How to improve this LINQ query for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369357/how-to-improve-this-linq-query-for-search)

### Edit 1

You can combine two condition in `or` clouse

```
  (LIKE '%[^a-z]'+@p+'[^a-z]%') OR (LIKE @p +`%`)
```

References : [Search for “whole word match” with SQL Server LIKE pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern)

You can also use

```
[MyColumn] Like '% '+  @p +' %' 
OR [MyColumn] Like '% '+ @p 
OR [MyColumn] Like ' %' 
OR [MyColumn] =  @p
```

Edit: An alternate approach (only for ascii chars) could be:

```
'#'+[MyColumn]+'#' like '%[^a-z0-9]'+ @p+'[^a-z0-9]%'
```

References [Match only entire words with LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283767/match-only-entire-words-with-like)

Comment: I have 3 words in name column, as in question. search should be performed on initial of either word.

Comment: I gave example with name of a cricketer in my updated question. Doesn't matter you search with first name, last name or middle name. It should give me result.